# How to distort images

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation

Is it possible to distort an image with open source software on Ubuntu?

I know I can skew and stretch, but how can I do [something like this](http://www.coloribus.com/adsarchive/prints/nike-air-zoom-swift-vapor-distort-5715855/)?

Basically, imagine all those images being a single png file, how would I give it that curved effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has an excellent image editing software called GIMP. You can goto the software center, and search for GIMP.  As for warping, I think you can do it.

Comment: Yes you can! Select a region of interest (be it a rectangle or whatever else) and apply the kind of distortion wanted, eg. IWarp

Comment: It would be swell if the two people who down voted also gave a reason so as to why.

Comment: @theTuxRacer because the answer doesn't provide an actual solution. GIMP may be able to do it but you do not detail how